# How to find the area of triangle formed by two a vector and its projection?

Tags: proof-verification, vectors

> Find the area of triangle formed by vector $u=\langle 3,4\rangle$ and its projection onto vector $b=\langle 2,1\rangle$.

In order to find the projection:
$$
\operatorname{proj}_bu=\frac{ub}{||b||^2}b=\langle 4,2\rangle
$$
We can calculate the area: $S=0.5||b||\cdot||u-\operatorname{proj}_bu||=0.5\cdot \sqrt 5\cdot \sqrt5=2.5$.

I know this seems an easy task but I'm wondering if the calculation is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct formula should be

$$S=0.5||\operatorname{proj}_bu||\cdot||u-\operatorname{proj}_bu||$$
rather than 
$$S=0.5||b||\cdot||u-\operatorname{proj}_bu||$$

Edit:

Since the $||\operatorname{proj}_bu||=2||b||$, the answer would be $5$.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively (to verify): let $\alpha$ be the angle between the vectors $u$ and $b$, then:
$$\cos{\alpha}=\frac{u\cdot b}{|u|\cdot |b|}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}} \Rightarrow \sin{\alpha}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}.$$
The area of the triangle:
$$S=\frac{1}{2}\cdot ||u||\cdot ||u-proj_b u||\cdot \sin{\alpha}=\frac{1}{2}\cdot 5\cdot 2\sqrt{5}\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}=5.$$